# How to close tcp connection shared by multiple processes?

Tags: linux, network-programming

1. There are 1 user space process A, 1 kernel space process B
2. process A open a tcp connection to some dst, and give the connection to process B. process B uses this connection to communicate with the dst

**How to terminate the tcp connection via process A?**

1. I have tried close(fd) in process A, this doesn't work, because process B still have a copy of this connection.
2. I have tried shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR) in process A, this doesn't work, because shutdown leaves the connection still valid.
3. Also kill process A can't terminate the tcp connection, i can still find this connection in netstat.

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor actually it's open-iscsi, i am hacking it to add some new feature. iscsid is user space process A, and iscsid-driver is kernel process B.

Comment: how about just use IPC?

Comment: @pengu What have you tried? (show code!)

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I have tried close, shutdown and kill process, all can't work. The code base is open-iscsi. Actually, this can be another question, if i know the fd, how can i know the src port of this tcp connection?

Comment: @pengdu "CODE" means source code that you've written. Where is it? Can we see it?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh https://gist.github.com/pdu/6265563

Comment: @pengdu That's a single source file. How are you building it with respect to the Linux kernel. How are you loading this code? (Give us details so we can reproduce the issue!)